# Subclass of UIview Calling autorelease causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

Please explain why if you are down voting.
I have a subclass of UIView for tableview section header

```
@interface ContactSectionHeaderView()

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *headerTitle;

@end

@implementation ContactSectionHeaderView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self){
        id rootView = [[self class] viewSizedForDevice];
        [rootView setFrame:frame];
        self = rootView;
    }

    return self;
}


+ (id) viewSizedForDevice {
    UINib* nib = [self nib];
    NSArray * nibObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    NSAssert2(([nibObjects count] > 0) &&
              [[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[self class]],
              @"Nib '%@' does not appear to contain a value %@",
              [self nibName], NSStringFromClass([self class]));
    id rootView = nibObjects[0];
    return rootView;
}

+(UINib*)nib {
    NSBundle * classBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:[self nibName] bundle:classBundle];
    return nib;
}

+ (NSString *)nibName {
    return [self viewIdentifier];
}

+ (NSString *)viewIdentifier {
    static NSString* _viewIdentifier = @"ContactSectionHeaderView";
    _viewIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    return _viewIdentifier;
}

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title {
    self.headerTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",title];    
}
- (void)dealloc {
    self.headerTitle = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I am using like this in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
 ContactSectionHeaderView *sectionHeader = [[[ContactSectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:[tableView rectForHeaderInSection:section]] autorelease];
```

This `autorelease` is causing the crash. If I remove the autorelease, then it works perfectly. How do I fix the crash?

Comment: Your project is ARC or non-ARC ?

Comment: You don't need to use `autorelease` as everything is now arc, its done automatically, you are using stone age code.

Comment: My project is in non ARC @AshishThakkar

Comment: @iphonic, yes it is a stone age project.

Comment: @tausun Covert it to ARC, and remove non-arc code.

Comment: where is your viewForHeaderInSection code?
do something like this-
[sectionHeader release];
[sectionHeader addSubiew:(ANyLabel or something)];

Comment: how can i add subview to something that is already released? @SahebSingh

Comment: my bad...[sectionHeader autorelease];
Then add subview.

Comment: I  have tried this, but still crashes.... :( @SahebSingh

Answer (score -1):

Remove `autorelease`. There is no need to use retain, release methods with ARC. ARC does it for you

Comment: My project is in non-ARC